# rsync ubuntu to windows under cygwin - way to avoid 'invalid argument 22' error?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, rsync, cygwin

I'm doing a backup from a ubuntu server to a windows machine running cygwin. I'm using the following command:

```
rsync -avx --timeout=30 --delete-excluded --exclude '.git' rsync@server.com:/var/www/site/ /cygdrive/c/temp/sitebackuprsync/
```

Is there a way (ie a command parameter) to avoid getting the 'Invalid argument 22' errors?

--

edit
This is an example of one of the errors

```
rsync: chown "/cygdrive/c/temp/sitebackuprsync/tmp/cache/meta/f4/.3b896ab05c69a5c1da040df249f764a2fad29a.RHbrGk" failed: Invalid argument (22)
```

Comment: From where you are executing this command. I mean from UBUNTU_server or from WINDOWS machine?.

Comment: I'm doing a pull, running this command on the windows machine to pull from the remote ubuntu machine.

Comment: Can you show us the exact error message that you are seeing as well as sample filenames (if applicable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-a` flag to `rsync` includes a number of options that don't make sense on Windows; the error you're seeing indicates that `rsync` is trying and failing to preserve file ownership. Try using `-rtvx` instead of `-avx`.